# BeanComparator generates a NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, comparator

just trying to use a BeanComparator but I get some errors that I do not manage to resolve:

```
BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator("age");
        Collections.sort(myList, comparator);


        comparator = new BeanComparator("name");
        Collections.sort(myList, comparator);

    comparator = new BeanComparator("sickness");
    Collections.sort(myList, comparator);
```

Running this code generates the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparableComparator
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator.<init>(BeanComparator.java:81)
    at testBeanComparator.TestBeanComparator.main(TestBeanComparator.java:23)
```

This is a basic java application that I set to isolate the BeanComparator issue.
I included the jar with maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils-bean-collections</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea what causes this mess?

Thx in advance.

Comment: check whtether your maven dependency consists commons-beanutils jar file by right click on your project and check the maven dependencies

Comment: @Shriram : It does contain commons-beanutils.beans-collections-1.8.3.jar

I would expect this one to do the trick right?

Comment: try adding commons-logging.jar and commons-collections.jar in your project

Comment: It is also included (1.1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have `commons-beanutils.jar` along with that `commons-logging.jar` and `commons-collections.jar`. I tried following `commons-beanutils-1.9.2 , commons-logging-1.2, commons-collections-3.2.1`

Comment: Good job Bakki, it was a question of libraries versions.
I upgraded from 1.8 to 1.9.2 and it worked.
Thx a ton for your assistance my friend.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building the maven project with the dependency in eclipse will build the jar and the output jar file is maven local repository as the location you mentioned. 
After building the jar if you need to execute the jar file you should add the commons-beanutils in the class path to execute the jar.
ie) java -jar  -cp 
As you said dependency is missed so try to add the dependency and you can verify that by right click on project and click build path and click maven dependencies. 
If you are building by running mvn command manually then you will get an error when your dependency is missing while building jar file.